# How to display model summary when using keras model with class method for Bert?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, bert-language-model

I went through this tutorial from [this tutorial from tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/bert_glue).

As described in there I defined my model with:

```
class Classifier(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(Classifier, self).__init__(name="prediction")
        self.encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder, trainable=True)
        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)

    def call(self, preprocessed_text):
        encoder_outputs = self.encoder(preprocessed_text)
        pooled_output = encoder_outputs["pooled_output"]
        x = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        x = self.dense(x)
        return x
```

I would like to display the model details after building it with `mode.summary()`. Unfortunately this only returns

> Model: "prediction"
>
> ---
>
> Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
>
> =================================================================
> keras_layer_1 (KerasLayer)  multiple                  109482241
>
> dropout_10 (Dropout)        multiple                  0
>
> dense_10 (Dense)            multiple                  4614
>
> =================================================================
> Total params: 109,486,855 Trainable params: 109,486,854 Non-trainable
> params: 1
>
> ---

But I would like to get the full layers in detail. Therefore I tried to add a function to create it in the model:

```
def summary_model(self, sequence_length):
    in_id = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(sequence_length,), name="input_ids")
    in_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(sequence_length,), name="input_masks")
    in_segment = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(sequence_length,), name="segment_ids")
    bert_inputs = [in_id, in_mask, in_segment]

    bert_output = self.encoder(bert_inputs)
    pooled_output = bert_output["pooled_output"]
    x = self.dropout(pooled_output)
    output = self.dense(x)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=bert_inputs, outputs=output)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()

    return model
```

But this leads to an error with

> ValueError: Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded
> from the SavedModel. Got: Positional arguments (3 total):
>
> - [<tf.Tensor 'inputs:0' shape=(None, 124) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'inputs_1:0' shape=(None, 124) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'inputs_2:0'
>   shape=(None, 124) dtype=float32>]
> - False
> - None Keyword arguments: {}
>
> Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):
>
> Option 1: Positional arguments (3 total):
>
> - {'input_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_mask'), 'input_type_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None),
>   dtype=tf.int32, name='input_type_ids'), 'input_word_ids':
>   TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_word_ids')}
> - False
> - None Keyword arguments: {}
>
> Option 2: Positional arguments (3 total):
>
> - {'input_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/input_mask'), 'input_type_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None,
>   None), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/input_type_ids'),
>   'input_word_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32,
>   name='inputs/input_word_ids')}
> - False
> - None Keyword arguments: {}
>
> Option 3: Positional arguments (3 total):
>
> - {'input_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/input_mask'), 'input_type_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None,
>   None), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/input_type_ids'),
>   'input_word_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32,
>   name='inputs/input_word_ids')}
> - True
> - None Keyword arguments: {}
>
> Option 4: Positional arguments (3 total):
>
> - {'input_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_mask'), 'input_type_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, None),
>   dtype=tf.int32, name='input_type_ids'), 'input_word_ids':
>   TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_word_ids')}
> - True
> - None Keyword arguments: {}

What do I need to change in the input shape or somewhere else to be able to get the detailed summary?

Comment: It expects int32 tensors, in Input

Comment: Have you tried the `expand_nested` parameter of the model's summary method?

Comment: @HansQ the above shown output was generated with `expand_nested` set to true

Comment: @elbe I tried that above. It leads to basically the same error:
`ValueError: Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
 Positional arguments (3 total):
 * [<tf.Tensor 'inputs:0' shape=(None, 12) dtype=int32>,
  <tf.Tensor 'inputs_1:0' shape=(None, 12) dtype=int32>,
  <tf.Tensor 'inputs_2:0' shape=(None, 12) dtype=int32>]
 * False
 * None
 Keyword arguments: {}`

Comment: Did you try `tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32)`?

Comment: @elbe just tried that now for all 3 layers, gives me basically the same error with just a slightly adjusted positional argument where shape is `shape=(None, None)`